# about pybind11 Return to the c++ array modification problem question

Tags: python, c++, c, pybind11

c++

How to return the `xyz` array without changing the definition of the `Tile` structure? You can use the subscript to modify the value

```c++
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Tile {
    float xyz[3];
};

struct Vector3d
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector3d(float x, float y, float z) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }

    Tile* pTile = 0;
    /*
    struct *p01 = 0;
    struct *p02 = 0;
    ....
    */
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(bbbb, m)
{
    py::class_<Vector3d>(m, "Vector3d")
        .def(py::init<float, float, float>())
        .def_property("x", [](Vector3d& p)->float {
            return p.x;
        }, [](Vector3d &p, float x) {
            p.x = x;
            if (p.pTile)
                p.pTile->xyz[0] = x;
        });

    py::class_<Tile>(m, "Tile")
        .def(py::init <>())
        .def_property("xyz", [](Tile& p)->py::array {
            auto dtype = pybind11::dtype(pybind11::format_descriptor<float>::format());
            return pybind11::array(dtype, { 3 }, { sizeof(float) }, p.xyz, nullptr);
        }, [](Tile& p) {})
        .def_property("vec_xyz", [](Tile& p)->Vector3d {
            Vector3d vec(p.xyz[0], p.xyz[1], p.xyz[2]);
            vec.pTile = &p;
            return vec;
        }, [](Tile& p) {})
        .def("__repr__", [](const Tile &p) { 
            char buff[100] = { 0 };
            sprintf(buff, "x:%f y:%f z:%f", p.xyz[0], p.xyz[1], p.xyz[2]);
            return std::string(buff, strlen(buff));;
        });
}
```

python

```python
>>> import bbbb
>>> t = bbbb.Tile()
>>> print(t)
x:0.000000 y:0.000000 z:0.000000
>>> t.xyz[0] = 1.5 #Modifying the value does not work
>>> print(t)
x:0.000000 y:0.000000 z:0.000000
>>> t.vec_xyz.x = 2.5 #Values can be modified
>>> print(t)
x:2.500000 y:0.000000 z:0.000000
>>>
```

How to make `t.xyz[0] = 1.5` work without changing the definition of the `Tile` structure

If there are multiple similar structures, you need to add structure pointers one by one in `Vector3D`, which is too troublesome

is there a better way than to return to `Vector3D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c++

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Tile1 { //Assume that the imported library cannot modify the definition
    float xyz[3];
};

struct Tile2 { //Assume that the imported library cannot modify the definition
    short xyz[6];
};

template<typename TT, typename A, typename B>
struct List {

    TT& m_obj;
    B TT::*pp;

    List(TT& obj, B TT::*pm) : m_obj(obj), pp(pm) {

    }

    void set(int i, A v) {
        if (i >= size()) {
            py::pybind11_fail("IndexError: list index out of range");
        }
        (m_obj.*pp)[i] = v;
    }

    A get(int i) {
        if (i >= size()) {
            py::pybind11_fail("IndexError: list index out of range");
        }
        return (m_obj.*pp)[i];
    }

    int size() {
        return sizeof((m_obj.*pp)) / sizeof((m_obj.*pp)[0]);
    }
};

#define LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B) List<TT, A, A[B]>
#define LIST_DEFINE_TILE1 LIST_DEFINE(Tile1, float, 3)
#define LIST_DEFINE_TILE2 LIST_DEFINE(Tile2, short, 6)
#define LIST_DEFINE_NEW(TT,A,B,M) \
py::class_<LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B)>(M, "List_"#A"_"#B) \
.def("__getitem__", [](LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B)& p, int i) { return p.get(i); }) \
.def("__setitem__", [](LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B)& p, int i, A v) { p.set(i, v); }) \
.def_property_readonly("length", [](LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B)& p) { return p.size(); })

void init_Tile1(py::module& m) {

    py::class_<Tile1>(m, "Tile1")
        .def(py::init <>())
        .def_property_readonly("xyz", [](Tile1& p) {
        return LIST_DEFINE_TILE1(p, &Tile1::xyz);
    })
        .def("__repr__", [](const Tile1 &p) {
        char buff[100] = { 0 };
        sprintf(buff, "x:%f y:%f z:%f", p.xyz[0], p.xyz[1], p.xyz[2]);
        return std::string(buff, strlen(buff));;
    });

    LIST_DEFINE_NEW(Tile1, float, 3, m); //List_flost_3

}

void init_Tile2(py::module& m) {

    py::class_<Tile2>(m, "Tile2")
        .def(py::init <>())
        .def_property_readonly("xyz", [](Tile2& p) {
        return LIST_DEFINE_TILE2(p, &Tile2::xyz);
    })
        .def("__repr__", [](const Tile2 &p) {
        char buff[100] = { 0 };
        sprintf(buff, "ax:%d ay:%d az:%d\nbx:%d by:%d bz:%d",
            p.xyz[0], p.xyz[1], p.xyz[2],
            p.xyz[3], p.xyz[4], p.xyz[5]);
        return std::string(buff, strlen(buff));
    });

    LIST_DEFINE_NEW(Tile2, short, 6, m); //List_short_6
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(bbbb, m)
{
    init_Tile1(m);
    init_Tile2(m);  
}
```

python

```
>>> import bbbb
>>> a = bbbb.Tile1()
>>> a.xyz.length
3
>>> a
x:0.000000 y:0.000000 z:0.000000
>>> a.xyz[1] = 1.5 #Can modify the value and work
>>> a
x:0.000000 y:1.500000 z:0.000000
>>> b = bbbb.Tile2()
>>> b.xyz.length
6
>>> b
ax:0 ay:0 az:0
bx:0 by:0 bz:0
>>> b.xyz[5] = 100 #Can modify the value and work
>>> b
ax:0 ay:0 az:0
bx:0 by:0 bz:100
```

A few days after I posted the question and no one replied to me, I came up with a temporary solution during this time, but it is still unavoidable that if there are arrays of different types and lengths, you need to define different types of `List_type_n` to return, by the way Ask if there is a better solution than this

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted then

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LIST_DEFINE_NEW(TT,A,B,M) \
py::class_<LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B)>(M, "List_"#A"_"#B) \
.def("__getitem__", [](LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B)& p, int i) { return p.get(i); }) \
.def("__setitem__", [](LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B)& p, int i, A v) { p.set(i, v); }) \
.def_property_readonly("length", [](LIST_DEFINE(TT,A,B)& p) { return p.size(); })

void init_Tile1(py::module& m){
    //......
    LIST_DEFINE_NEW(Tile1, float, 3, m);
}
```

It can also be defined as a macro definition to facilitate adding definitions of different types and lengths

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).